# Pegar dados de um array JSON e adicionar a uma lista em Java WEB

Tags: java, json

Tenho uma lista em JSON:

```
 {"_status":"sucesso","_dados":{"situacao":"PROCESSADO","mensagem":"Consulta realizada com sucesso","processados":0,"titulos":[],"titulosNaoConciliados":[{"Ocorrencias":[],"CodigosOcorrencias":[],"CodigoMovimento":"06","TituloNossoNumero":"162023418","TituloNossoNumeroOriginal":"2341","TituloDataVencimento":null,"PagamentoValorPago":"74","PagamentoValorCredito":"0,00","PagamentoValorTaxaCobranca":"0,00","PagamentoValorAcrescimos":"0,00","PagamentoData":"16/06/2016","PagamentoDataCredito":"17/06/2016","PagamentoRealizado":true,"TituloNumeroDocumento":""},{"Ocorrencias":[],"CodigosOcorrencias":[],"CodigoMovimento":"28","TituloNossoNumero":"162023418","TituloNossoNumeroOriginal":"2341","TituloDataVencimento":null,"PagamentoValorPago":"74","PagamentoValorCredito":"0,00","PagamentoValorTaxaCobranca":"1,8","PagamentoValorAcrescimos":"0,00","PagamentoData":"16/06/2016","PagamentoDataCredito":"16/06/2016","PagamentoRealizado":false,"TituloNumeroDocumento":""},{"Ocorrencias":[],"CodigosOcorrencias":[],"CodigoMovimento":"06","TituloNossoNumero":"162025348","TituloNossoNumeroOriginal":"2534","TituloDataVencimento":null,"PagamentoValorPago":"100","PagamentoValorCredito":"0,00","PagamentoValorTaxaCobranca":"0,00","PagamentoValorAcrescimos":"0,00","PagamentoData":"16/06/2016","PagamentoDataCredito":"17/06/2016","PagamentoRealizado":true,"TituloNumeroDocumento":""},{"Ocorrencias":[],"CodigosOcorrencias":[],"CodigoMovimento":"28","TituloNossoNumero":"162025348","TituloNossoNumeroOriginal":"2534","TituloDataVencimento":null,"PagamentoValorPago":"100","PagamentoValorCredito":"0,00","PagamentoValorTaxaCobranca":"1,8","PagamentoValorAcrescimos":"0,00","PagamentoData":"16/06/2016","PagamentoDataCredito":"16/06/2016","PagamentoRealizado":false,"TituloNumeroDocumento":""},{"Ocorrencias":[],"CodigosOcorrencias":[],"CodigoMovimento":"06","TituloNossoNumero":"162026735","TituloNossoNumeroOriginal":"2673","TituloDataVencimento":null,"PagamentoValorPago":"21,13","PagamentoValorCredito":"0,00","PagamentoValorTaxaCobranca":"0,00","PagamentoValorAcrescimos":"0,00","PagamentoData":"16/06/2016","PagamentoDataCredito":"17/06/2016","PagamentoRealizado":true,"TituloNumeroDocumento":""},{"Ocorrencias":[],"CodigosOcorrencias":[],"CodigoMovimento":"28","TituloNossoNumero":"162026735","TituloNossoNumeroOriginal":"2673","TituloDataVencimento":null,"PagamentoValorPago":"21,13","PagamentoValorCredito":"0,00","PagamentoValorTaxaCobranca":"1,8","PagamentoValorAcrescimos":"0,00","PagamentoData":"16/06/2016","PagamentoDataCredito":"16/06/2016","PagamentoRealizado":false,"TituloNumeroDocumento":""}]}}
```

Preciso pegar essa lista e pegar somente os dados:

- TituloNossoNumero: 162023418
- PagamentoRealizado": true

E ir adicionando em uma lista.

Alguém poderia ajudar? Não sei nem por onde começar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salvei o seu JSON em um arquivo `meujson2.json`.

Criei essa classe para representar os itens da lista:

```
public final class PagamentoRealizado {
    private final String tituloNossoNumero;
    private final boolean pagamentoRealizado;

    public PagamentoRealizado(String tituloNossoNumero, boolean pagamentoRealizado) {
        this.tituloNossoNumero = tituloNossoNumero;
        this.pagamentoRealizado = pagamentoRealizado;
    }

    public String getTituloNossoNumero() {
        return tituloNossoNumero;
    }

    public boolean isPagamentoRealizado() {
        return pagamentoRealizado;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return tituloNossoNumero + " - " + pagamentoRealizado;
    }
}
```

Criei esse código para criar a lista:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.json.JsonReader;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonValue;

public class LerJson2 {

    private static List<PagamentoRealizado> pagamentosDoJson(String json)
            throws IOException
    {
        JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(json));
        JsonObject status = reader.readObject();
        JsonObject dados = status.getJsonObject("_dados");
        JsonArray titulosNaoConciliados = dados.getJsonArray("titulosNaoConciliados");
        return titulosNaoConciliados
                .stream()
                .map(titulo -> {
                    JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) titulo;
                    String tituloNossoNumero = obj.getString("TituloNossoNumero");
                    boolean pagamentoRealizado = obj.getBoolean("PagamentoRealizado");
                    return new PagamentoRealizado(tituloNossoNumero, pagamentoRealizado);
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("meujson2.json");
        String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        List<PagamentoRealizado> pagamentos = pagamentosDoJson(json);
        System.out.println(pagamentos);
    }
}
```

Utilizei [essa biblioteca](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.1.2/javax.json-1.1.2.jar) e [essa outra](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/json/javax.json-api/1.1.2/javax.json-api-1.1.2.jar) para colocar no classpath.

Compilei com essa linha de comando:

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 -cp javax.json-1.1.2.jar;javax.json-api-1.1.2.jar LerJson2.java
```

E executei assim:

```
java -cp javax.json-1.1.2.jar;javax.json-api-1.1.2.jar;. LerJson2
```

Eis a saída:

```
[162023418 - true, 162023418 - false, 162025348 - true, 162025348 - false, 162026735 - true, 162026735 - false]
```

Comment: Amigo obrigado pela resposta, mais estou utilizando java web, tentei adaptar mais não consegui

Comment: @LeandroSantos O código do main deve funcionar dentro de um servlet ou dentro de algum outro método qualquer. Talvez você não queira ler de um arquivo, mas esse código monta o JSOn diretamente de uma String que você pode pegar em qualquer lugar. Ele monta uma `List<PagamentoRealizado>` que você pode passar para onde quiser, o `System.out.println` no final é só para mostrar que funciona.

Comment: @LeandroSantos Separei o método `pagamentosDoJson` do resto do `main` para facilitar a tarefa de adaptar o código para onde você precisar.

Comment: a sim, o que seria o titulo -> ?

Comment: @LeandroSantos É a declaração de um lambda, uma característica da linguagem Java introduzida no Java 8.

Comment: Estou recebendo um erro nesta linha

Comment: @LeandroSantos Qual erro? Qual é a sua versão do Java?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79764/discussion-between-leandro-santos-and-victor-stafusa).